# Turn the Lights on/off wirelessly

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, hardware

I just bought my Raspberry Pi 3 today and I want to wirelessly turn the lights on/off.

I did some research on google but I am confused.

What are the requirements to do this?

```
1-) Raspberry pi 
2-) ..
3-) ..
```

etc..

Comment: What type of lights (Lamps that plug into a wall socket or lights controlled by a wall switch)? Do they run AC or DC? What voltage do they run at? can you flash an LED yet; if not  I suggest you start there. Unless you are using a WiFi controlled socket or lamp this will require toggling one of the Pi's GPIO pins - just like you do when blinking an LED. Remember the best way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time. By that I mean break the project down into smaller more manageable steps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this on your hardware side https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/119

Then you just have to control a +5v output to the relay board.  I'm just starting this myself as a Proof of Concept to start running down a PLC type of road, but rest based.  I know there's probably existing frameworks, but thats not why I do it. :)